# Using jQuery .load to add rows to an html table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, html-table

The code below adds the `html` returned by `returndatafromdb2()` function in the server to the table that has id `resultstable2`. The html returned by the function `returndatafromdb2()` is of the form:

```
"<tr><td>some text</td><td>more text</td></tr><tr><td>some text</td><td>more text</td></tr><tr><td>some text</td><td>more text</td></tr>"
```

As you can see in the code I am using `.load()` from jquery to obtain the `html` from the server and add it to the table. The code I am using, however, replaces the existing rows in the table instead of adding to it. How can I use jQuery `.load()` function to add the rows to existing rows and not replace them?

If I can somehow assign the html received from the `.load()` function to a variable say `newhtml`, I can do something like `$(newhtmltext).appendTo('#resultstable2')`. But I don't know how to assign the html obtained by `.load()` to a variable, or to use it as a string.

**The Code:**

## Create table using jquery

```
<p>Method 2</p>

    <table id="resultstable2">
        <tr>
            <th>Grade</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </table>

<button id="b2">Execute returndatafromdb2()</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajaxSetup({
        cache: false
    });


    var getdata2 = function(){
        var loadurl2 = "{{=URL('default', 'returndatafromdb2')}}";
        $('#resultstable2').load(loadurl2));
    };

    $('#b2').click(getdata2);

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do it with the `load()` function. You will want to use the normal ajax calls and write your own callback function. Something like this:

```
var getdata2 = function() {

    var loadurl2 = "{{=URL('default', 'returndatafromdb2')}}";
    $.get(loadurl2,function(data){
        $('#resultstable2').append(data);   
    },'html');

};

$('#b2').click(getdata2);
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew how to do it with $.get and $.post. Was wondering if it was possible with load.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `append` instead of `load()`

```
var getdata2 = function() { 
    var loadurl2 = "{{=URL('default', 'returndatafromdb2')}}";
    $.get(loadurl2,function(data){
        //Here goes the append :-)
        $('#resultstable2').append(data);   
    },'html');
};

$('#b2').click(getdata2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.get( loadurl2 ,'', function(d){

$('#resultstable2').append(d);

} )
```