# Is there a better way than using jQuery and timestamps to update a table?

Tags: php, jquery, html-table, timestamping

The following 'bit' of code, creates a standard html page with a simple table, displaying messages and their timestamps (that could potentially be presented nicer, but atm never mind.

The PHP first retrieves all of the messages (from a particular updated timestamp onwards, if provided). It uses [PDO to retrieve records (for DB abstraction reasons)](http://gr2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php). If the timestamp is provided, it encodes the content in json, returns that and dies (Ah, the murdering semantics). If not, it continues and returns a complete html page, where all of the records are shown in a table, as well as a button, that, when pressed, will call the same PHP script with a timestamp, to retrieve any updated messages since the meantime, and updates the related table row cells.

I think that, although basic, this works very nicely. It uses jQuery well to update any relative updates, and I guess something very similarly could work very well for a little html chat, where the table_update function is called every two seconds, or time exponentially incrementing.

**Question**: Are there any good practice coding out there, that could make this even better?

For example, I wonder whether giving TR any id is a good idea; the PDO code block is a bit of a mixed purée, and I over-enjoy seeing the DIE() function used in a productive way, when normally I have only seen it for post-error mortem-handling, security check-failures, or false script includes.

Any good developers out there, who used to do this, and are now using better approaches?

I don't want frameworks, I want something relatively simple, for eg. flash-pages.

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT id, message, timestamp
    FROM messages
    WHERE id_user = :id_user';
if(isset($_REQUEST["timestamp"]))
{
 $sql .= ' && timestamp >= :timestamp';
}
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));
$sth->execute(array(':id_user' => $id_user, ':timestamp' => $_REQUEST["timestamp"]));
$data = $sth->fetchAll();

if(isset($_REQUEST["timestamp"]))
{
 echo json_encode($data);
 die();
}

?>
<html>
 <head>...</head>
<body>
<input id='button_check' value='Update this table' type='button' />
<table id="table_check">
    <tr>
        <th>Message</th>
        <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach($data as $record) { ?>
    <tr id="tr_<?php echo $record["id"] ?>">
        <td><?php echo $record["strNumber"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $record["strFullName"] ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var intLastUpdate = <?php echo time() ?>;
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#button_check').click(update_table());
});

function update_table()
{
 $.getJSON("this_page.php?timestamp=" + intLastUpdate, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, record) {
            $('#tr_' + record.id).find("td").eq(0).html(record.message);
            $('#tr_' + record.timestamp).find("td").eq(1).html(record.timestamp);
            if(intLastUpdate < record.timestamp) {
                intLastUpdate = record.timestamp;
            }
        });
    });
}
</script>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11868223/using-jquery-load-to-add-rows-to-an-html-table

Comment: I like that, but that then means you need to generate the TBODY innerHTML BEFORE you determine if the entire layout is needed and DIEEE(), and it's generally considered a bad practice to mix html with server code. Also, your referenced method requires the server to load ALL contents when only very few rows/records may require updating? This being said, your reference is a very interesting alternative.